# Url error on lookupfields causes webpart to fail

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, custom-list, office-365

I’ve setup up two lists.

A main list(list A) and a secondary list(list B).

These two lists are related through lookupfields, where list B looks up items in list A. On the DispForm.aspx for list A, i’ve added a related list(list B) as a viewpart.

When i open an item on list A, it correctly shows the related items in list B.*
[image]
However, if i open an item on list B and click the lookupfield, the viewpart breaks and gives a correlation error.* 
[image]

Since i’m on SharePoint online, i’m not able to debug any logs.

My question is therefore, is this intended behavioure or is this a bug? I can see that when clicking on list B, the url for the item on list A is different than what visiting list A directly. It would see that going through list B, SharePoint appends a "rootfolder=%2A" or "rootfolder=*" to the end of the url. Removing the characters after "=" fixes the issue.

*(The images are from a norwegian SharePoint, but it would be the same in any other language i guess, the errormessage on the second image is just the ordinary "cannot show this webpart")

Comment: Just stabbing in the dark here, but try disabling MDS, maybe it's causing issues.

Comment: No, that didn't work. I've edited my post and added some screenshots to further explain the issue i'm experiencing.

Comment: @Alexander Edit would be a good thing

Comment: Are lists A and B on the same site?

Comment: Yes, both lists are on the same site. I also recreated on a clean subsite just to be sure it wasnt any deployed wsp or edited masterpage issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix doesn't work on a list with pagination as the list items in the extra pages are obtained via ajax, so this doesn't correct the links for the rest of the pages (as the js doesn't run again).

You can either get it to run again after someone has clicked to view a different page page buttons (AFTER the ajax has got the data and put it on the page), or I'm just running it every couple of seconds:

```js
$(window).load(function() {

    function fixurls(){
        $('.ms-listviewtable tbody a').each(function() {
            try {
                $(this).attr('onclick',$(this).attr('onclick').replace('RootFolder=*','RootFolder='));
                $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('RootFolder=*','RootFolder='));
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log("Found RootFolder replace exception but ignoring it...");
            }
        });
    }

    function run_fixurls(){
        fixurls();
        setTimeout(run_fixurls, 2000);
    }

    run_fixurls();

});
```

Comment: Changed the correct answer to yours, since its "more" correct as it handles pagination as well.

Answer (score 1):

I made contact with 365 support and they could not figure out directly what happens here, so they assisted with a workaround for it.

To enable this sort of retrospection in the lookups I added https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js to SiteAssets aswell as this small script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ms-listviewtable a').each(function() {
                 $(this).attr('onclick',$(this).attr('onclick').replace('RootFolder=*','RootFolder='));
                 $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('RootFolder=*','RootFolder='));
});});
```

Now to get this working, I added the following to a scripteditor webpart for "List B"(through the "edit page" link)

```
<script src="../../SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/changeURL.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This solves the issue for me, and correct urls are linked between the listsviews.

Answer (score 0):

Over 3 years later and this is still an issue. :( I tried modifying this solution for a display form but am having some issues getting it working.  Anyone had any success using this solution on a display form that they could share?  I modified the function to select '#SPFieldLookupMulti a', but it seems to kill my form as nothing displays when it loads.  Not sure what the issue is.

**Update:**
I figured it out.  I removed the link modifying the onclick.  So end result was.

```
$("#SPFieldLookupMulti a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('RootFolder=*','RootFolder='));
});
```